# elastic-apm-node not register span after express responde

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, apm

I need to send span to elastic-apm after sending express response.

In my code example, i use setInterval. First express response, after 1 second, i try use startspan, but i got error: Cannot read property 'end' of null

```
const apm = require('elastic-apm-node').start();  
const app = require('express')(); app.get('/', (req, res) => {  
    setTimeout(() => {  
        span = apm.startSpan("My span");  
        span.end();  
    }, 100)  
    res.json({"teste": "TESTE"});
});
```

My elastic stack version is 7.6.2

Comment: Please try: if (span) span.end(); https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/nodejs/3.x/custom-spans.html

Comment: You correct the error, but do not send the span to the apm. The problem is that the apm ends when the response occurs, so the apm does not work in setTimeout.

I need a way to send the APM after the response.

Comment: @JoãoA.Zonta Any result with your problem resolution? I have this problem too.